# Object modelling - REST vs Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, web-services, soa

I am facing this in a project of my own, but i am sure this should be a generic issue.

I am trying to build rest services using java, spring and hibernate.
My typical entity object is modeled like below

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable{
    private Long companyId;
    private String name;
    private String shortDescription;
    private Long logoId;
    private Set<ActivityType> activityTypeList;
    private String address;
    private RegistrationInfo regInfo;
}
```

Where one object has associations with other objects, so my model object contains references to the associated objects.
I use jackson configured with spring for json-object and object-json conversion, it works perfectly, so I am good till this point.

Now I want my POST calls(which I am using for object creation) to create Company objects, only catch here is that I do not want to pass complete json for contained objects(like ActivityType and RegistrationInfo in above example), rather an id for each where the object with provided id already exists in the database. For example see this JSON snippet:

```
{
    "companyId": 5,
    "name": "test company created by rest call",
    "shortDescription": "dummy description",
    "logoId": 0,
    "activityTypeList": [
        {"activityTypeId": 1}
    ],
    "address": "202, kardoga lane, lonavala, Maharashtra",
    "regInfo": {
        "registrationInfoId": 1
    }
}
```

My rest service just needs to associate the newly created company object with the existing contained object with the provided id(inside POST call's body).
Jackson serialization creates unpopulated objects in this case, which hibernate fails to persist (for obvious reasons, there is no data just an id)

Sure i can use a DTO over here, i can get REST -> DTO and then DTO -> entity, but that seems an overhead and moreover in order to populate the Company object defined above, I will need to fetch the associated objects first from DB, attach them to my company object and then save it back. That will be an unnecessary DB trip.

Anyone has better idea on this one? Any design pattern, framework or simple tips/tricks in which i dont require a dto as well as save DB calls.

Comment: You don't need to fetch the data of the related entities. Only to get a reference to them (unless you want to check they actually exist). See EntityManager.getReference(). DTOs are the way to go, IMHO.